# How to remove a line after another line in a file with ansible?

Tags: ansible, file-processing

My ansible inventory contains a group that has dynamically generated IP addresses.

```
[asg]
10.15.100.13
10.15.100.14
```

Is it possible to remove the line after `[asg]`? (i.e. `10.15.100.13`)

The IP addresses in this group refers to the [ec2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances in an auto scaling group.

[lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module doesn't have a `removeafter` option.

I'd like to know if there are other alternative ways to remove the line after `[asg]`.

`regexp` option doesn't work. Because the IP addresses change frequently.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using dynamic inventory (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) instead of changing a static inventory with ansible itself. There are EC2 example in ansible source code.

Comment: So every single playbook execution will delete one line until `[asg]` is the last one in a file? That doesn't seem like a task you should employ Ansible for.

Comment: Playbook1 adds the ip address under `[asg]`.  Playbook2 uses this address. Playbook3 deletes the ip address under `[asg]`. That's the way I use ansible.

Comment: I'm afraid you dealing with an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/305121). Even if you have to stick to inventory files, why don't you simply write the entry to a separate file in the inventory directory and delete the file afterwards?

Comment: @Brian I'm really curious if you have tested [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44747868/2947502) before accepting it, because it is impossible that it replaces two lines, as it claims. At best it will add two lines to the end of the file.

Comment: @techraf you are right as `lineinfile` does not use multi-line mode. My intention was to use `replace` but I wasn't aware I was following the OP title when typing the answer...

Answer (score 3):

Totally possible with `replace` as long as regexp is supported.

```
- replace:
    path: /path/to/file
    regexp: '\[asg\]\n[^\n]+' # Matches [asg] and next line
    replace: '[asg]'          # Replace both lines with [asg]
```

Comment: I wonder whether you tried this before posting, because it has no way of working in Ansible. `lineinfile` module will never replace two lines.

Comment: Sorry I intended to use `replace`, which supports multiline mode regexp, instead of `lineinfile`.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: What happens if it finds no "asg"?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is possible using `lineinfile` or `blockinfile`, but you can achieve it using `sed`. **WARNING**: This solution is **not idempotent**.

```
- shell: /bin/sed -i.bak '/\[asg\]/{n;d}' my_inventory_file
```

The command will delete the line after `[asg]`. It will automatically create a backup file with `.bak` extension. Depending on your OS, the path to `sed` and the arguments may vary. You can refine the `regexp` further by:

```
- shell: sed -i.bak '/^\s*\[asg\]\s*$/{n;d}' my_inventory_file
```

`{n;d}` or `{n;d;} for MacOS` - read the line (n)ext to pattern and (d)elete it

Comment: I got `extra characters at the end of d command` error with this solution. I think it's because the version of my sed is BSD sed.

Comment: `- shell: /bin/sed -i.bak '/\[asg\]/{n;d;}' my_inventory_file` works on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: But I still don't understand the meaning of `n;` in this command.

Comment: I tried it on Ubuntu, it worked. You are correct, it needs a little tweak for MacOs.  @Brian I have added the meaning of `n`